# Looking for alternative Collaborative Developing Environments

Tags: development-environment, collaboration

I'm interested in Collaborative Developing and I was wondering if there are alternative solutions than using [UNA (example video)](http://www.vimeo.com/1653402) from N-Brain. Free would be even better, but I guess that's not an option which such technology.

PS: The main future I'm looking for is working real-time with multiple persons in the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in Mac world, [SubEthaEdit](http://www.subethaedit.net/) is a good option.  Not free, but €29 isn't bad.

Answer (score 1):

After some further searching around I have found **[Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/)**, seems to be much better than [MoonEdit](http://moonedit.com/).
Don't think there is any better free program that supports developing more than color coding.

I hope to have helped others too by this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Charlie I have found [MoonEdit](http://moonedit.com/), I'm still looking for better alternatives though...

Comment: checky mark?  +1?  (I'm not above a little reputation-whoring.)

Comment: Gave you some reputation (I forgot) and if after a some time there hasn't been a better solution, you will get the checky mark. ;-)